# Find minimum value in a python dataframe selecting only rows or columns contained in other df or list

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, minimum

Still a noob here so I have this issue. Using networkx I managed to get the minimum distances matrix between a series of nodes with the Dijkstra algorithm.

```
djk_dist=dict(nx.all_pairs_dijkstra_path_length(G, weight='L'))    
DJK=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(djk_dist).replace(0, np.nan)  #Minimum distances matrix
```

Now I need to automatically get some of this distances because I only want to know the smallest distance between 2 types of nodes (actually I will need the two shortest paths but I guess I can move to that after sorting the shortest). First node type I call SE and is obtained from an excel datasheet

```
is_SE=xpos.loc[:,'TYPE'] == 'SE'   #Select nodes of type SE
df_SE=xpos.loc[is_SE]       
dfSE=df_SE.loc[:, ['N', 'X', 'Y']]     
SEnodes=dfSE.loc[:, ['N']]        #Select only column N that defines node number
SE_nodes=SEnodes.values.tolist()
```

Same for the other type (VV)

```
is_VV=xpos.loc[:,'VV'] == 'SI'   
df_VV=xpos.loc[is_VV]       
df_VV=df_VV.loc[:, ['N', 'X', 'Y', 'TYPE']]
VVnodes=df_VV.loc[:, ['N']]
VV_nodes=VVnodes.values.tolist()
```

I tried a few things and ended up with this

```
for VLD in DJK.index: 
    VLD=VLD_nodes
    SE=SE_nodes
    minValues = DJK.loc[:,SE].idxmin()
    print(minValues)
```

Which gives the message
*"None of [Index([(29,), (30,)], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"*

But 29 and 30 are the values in the SE_nodes list (not in the index of the list though but not sure if this can be an issue)

Any help will be very wellcome

Comment: The error message tells you that pandas cannot find `29` and `30` among the columns (column names, not integer-based locations) of your `DJK` dataframe.  The `.loc[:, SE]` syntax tells pandas to get all rows and just the columns included in `SE`.  Run `DJK.head()` or `DJK.columns` to see what columns are contained in that `DJK` dataframe.

Comment: @AlexK  `DJK.head()` delivers a matrix identical to `DJK` dataframe. `DJK.columns` gives a single column with the integer values of the column names in `DJK` dataframe. This integer values include `29` and `30`. I got rid of the error setting inside the loop `for` this `SE=SEnodes.index` and `minValues = DJK.loc[VLDnodes, SE].min()` but this gives a single column with the minimum value of the rows with row name defined in `SEnodes`